# Send contents of PDF file to external API?

Tags: php, json, pdf, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

Using Gravity Forms, I have a php form with a PDF file upload field. We pass the form data (json) to a third party API. However, it is sending the PDF as a url to the file, and we need to actually pass the **contents** of the PDF encoded in the body.

We can use the following filter to modify the request data before the webhook is set, but I don't know how to encode the actual file contents:

```
add_filter( 'gform_webhooks_request_data', 'modify_data', 10, 4 );
function modify_data( $request_data, $feed, $entry, $form ){
  $request_data = // do something
  return $request_data;
}
```

How is it possible to read the file contents of the PDF and base64 encode it?

Thank you!

Comment: encode it as base64

Comment: In your question what actually creates the PDF? If it is what is returned by `modify_data` then change `return $request_data;` to `return base64_encode($request_data);`. If that isn't what is creating the PDF please [edit] your question and show us the code that does create the PDF.

Comment: I would think something like the following would do it: `$mypdf=file_get_contents('/path/to/.pdf'); $pdf64=base64_encode($mypdf);`

Comment: @Dave The PDF is uploaded from the user's desktop using a file upload field in the gravity form. We aren't creating the PDF file.

Comment: @JNevill, oh wow, I didn't realize it would be that simple! I was picturing having to extract the contents to text first. Does this work with any file (like a word doc) as well?

Comment: I believe `file_get_contents` reads the file in binary mode, so really any file can be gobbled up into a variable which you can then `base64` encode. I'm certain someone will quickly correct me if my assumptions are wrong.

Comment: I'm looking further into base64 encoding -- is there any reason I would also need to use chunk_split? Like `chunk_split(base64_encode($mypdf))`